# How can I import and play a video in Blender using a python script?

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

I want to import a video of any format into the scene and want to play it either from the start or some specific time using a python script.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Play it where? In the video sequence editor? On an object in the scene?

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a VSE strip of the video at a specified time?

Comment: Play it as an object in the scene.

Comment: @ Mutant Bob yes something similar to that.